# Jsoup is not stripping escaped html characters

Tags: java, json, jsoup

I have a standard json structure inside which I have content like this

`<p>`This is html content`<\/p>`

And I am using jsoup to strip the tags.However I am getting output as below

This is html content`</p>`

Jsoup is not able to strip the end tags which is having escaped characters.

Note:A standard json data format will consider `/` as special character and escapes it

Any standard json libraries available in java which can do this?

Comment: Can you post your code that strips the tags?

Answer (score 0):

`<\/p>` is not a valid closing tag. Jsoup tries to interpret the HTML according to the W3 standard. The `<p>` element does not always require a closing tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Since you did not provide the full HTML I can't tell you if the HTML is valid. However, JSoup also tries to make the best out of invalid HTML. (Hence the name of the library: JSoup, makes the best out of HTML-Soup)

In any case, if you find `<\/p>` in the HTML it is actually valid content, and not a closing tag, because the correct closing tag is `</p>`

So what JSoup does is exactly what should happen.

I think you may want to analyze the source of your HTML. It seems it went through some processing that changed the validity of the HTML. I guess you should try to feed JSoup with the original HTML instead.

I understand that your HTML is part of a JSON formatted string. Maybe you should try to analyze how this string is further processed to make valid HTML again out of it. Repeat this procedure and then feed it to JSoup